# ¿Cómo hacer en angular que al hacer clic en un botón éste me lleve a la vista donde se encontrarán los datos de un elemento con in id (parámetros)))

Tags: angular

soy nueva en angular. Les platico: estoy trabajando en una vista que me muestra todas las opciones de respuesta para una pregunta de un cuestionario,cada respuesta tiene un answerId que fue definido en un modelo, entonces en la vista de editarpregunta me trae todas las respuestas, al lado de cada respuesta hay un botón de editar y al dar clic en él  me tendría que mostrar solo la plantilla (vista formulario) para una respuesta que tiene cierto id.Pero lo que hace actualmente es que doy clic en cualquier editar y me lleva a la vista para editar todas las respuestas osea no me lleva solo a la del id del elemento, que es eso lo que necesito.
[image: imagen de la vista de las respuestas por pregunta] El código de la vista que me muestra todas las respuestas es este:

```html
<div *ngIf="modelo2 && modelo4" class="container" style="padding-left: 0;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
        <h3>Editar Pregunta</h3>
        
        <app-menu-editar-por-reactivo>
 <!--prueba felizgit checkout-->

        </app-menu-editar-por-reactivo>

        <div class="col-md-12 border border-dark contenedor mt-3">
          Pregunta {{modelo1.id}}
        </div>
        <!--fin caja negra-->
        <div class="col-md-12 border border-dark texto">

          <div class="texto mq">
            <div class="btnModificarReactivo">
              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" routerLink="/CrearPregunta">Modificar reactivo/configuración</button>
              Reactivo configurado para la pregunta:<strong> {{modelo1.id}} </strong> <span> del test:<strong>{{modelo2.name}}</strong></span>
            
            
            </div>
            <div class="contenido">
             {{modelo1.questionText}} 
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 d-flex flex-row" *ngFor="let option of modelo4; let index=index">
          
              <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8 demo-table" >
                <!-- Position Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="respuesta">
                 <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{option.answerText}} ></td>
                </ng-container>
              
                

                <!-- Name Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="editar">
                  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> </th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                    <!--<button mat-raised-button color="warn" focusable="false" (click)="editarReactivoPregunta()">
    Editar x reactivo
  </button>-->
                    <!--add-->
                    <a mat-flat-button color="warn" routerLink="/formularioEditarPorReactivo">
                      Editar
                    </a>
                  
                    <!--<button mat-flat-button color="warn" (click)="editar($event, question.id, answer.id)">-->
                      <button mat-flat-button color="warn" (click)="editar($event)">
                      Editar2
                    </button>
                  </td>
                </ng-container>
              
                
              
                <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns">  </tr>
               <tr
                    mat-row class="mat2"
                    (click)="clickedRows.add(row)"
                    [class.demo-row-is-clicked]="clickedRows.has(row)"
                    *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
                ></tr>
              
              </table>
              
             <!--- <div>
                <h3>
                  Click Log
                </h3>
              </div>
              
              <div *ngIf="!clickedRows.size">
                Clicked rows will be logged here
              </div>
              
              <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let clickedRow of clickedRows">
                  Clicked on {{clickedRow.name}}
                </li>
              </ul>-->



     
             </div>
            <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Su ts es este:

```html
  public previewRes: AnswerOptionGetDto= {};
  constructor( 
    //private cookieService:CookieService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private questionService:QuestionsService,
    private answerOption: AnswerOptionsService,
    //private testService: TestsService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router, 
    
    ){}
    form: FormGroup;
    @Input()
    tinymceInit;
    model:AnswerOptionGetDto;
  modelo: AnswerOptionGetPreviewDto;
   modelB:QuestionGetDto[]=[];
   modelC:AnswerOptionGetIdDto;
  questionId: number;
  languageCode:string;
  //answerOptionId: number;//a
   value:number;
   
   modelAnswerSearch:AnswerOptionGetDto[]=[];//1
   errores_api: string[] = [];
   order: number = 0;

    @Output()
    modelA:AnswerOptionGetDto[]=[];//1
   
  
    //OnSubmit: EventEmitter<QuestionGetIdDto> = new EventEmitter<QuestionGetIdDto>();
  OnSubmit: EventEmitter<AnswerOptionPostDto> = new EventEmitter<AnswerOptionPostDto>();
  pass: EventEmitter<AnswerOptionGetDto> = new EventEmitter<AnswerOptionGetDto>();
    OnCancel: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.questionId = params.questionId;
      this.languageCode = 'es',
      console.log('paso el ID:');
      console.log('paso el LC:');
    });
    this.getQuestionData(this.questionId);
    console.log("view 1");



    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      answerText: ['', { validators: [Validators.required] }],//a
      //value: (''),
      //order: (''),
      value: [0],
      order: [this.order]
    });
if (this.modelo !== undefined) {
      this.form.patchValue(this.modelo);
    }
    this.form.valueChanges
      .subscribe(valor => {

        this.buscarPorId(valor);
      });

    //this.getQuestionData(this.questionId);

    /*this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.testid = params.id;
      this.url = this.router.routerState.snapshot.url;
      //console.log('url ' + this.url);
    });
    }
  }*/
      this.getQuestionData(this.questionId);
      }

     buscarPorId(valor:any){
       var arr=[]
       var x: number
       this.modelAnswerSearch=[];
       this.modelA.forEach(x => {
       x===this.questionId? this.modelC=x:null}) ,
       console.log("modelC");
      console.log(x);
      console.log("modelAnswerSearch");
      console.log(this.modelAnswerSearch);
     
    }
  //});
  
     //}

       getQuestionData(questionId:number){
        this.answerOption.obtenerOpcionesPregunta$Json({
          questionId:1,
          //answerOptionId:1,
          languageCode: 'es',
          includeHATEOAS: 'n',
          platformId: 1,
          'x-languageCode': 'es',
      
        }).subscribe(respuesta=>{
          this.modelA=respuesta.answerOptions,
           this.modelAnswerSearch=respuesta.answerOptions;
           
           //this.modelB=respuesta.questions;
           console.log(this.modelAnswerSearch);
           //console.log(this.modelB)
        },  errores => {
          this.errores_api = parsearErroresAPI(errores);
          
        });
        

      
       }
  
  
      guardarCambios(){
       this.OnSubmit.emit(this.form.value);
       console.log("guardado");
    
      }
```

y lo que quiero es que al hacer clic en Editar me lleve sólo a la vista que corresponde a ese id de respuesta, actualmente me manda a todas
[image: imagen de todas las respuestas por pregunta].
el código ts para del formulario es :

```html
export class FormularioComponent implements OnInit {

  //add
  public previewRes: AnswerOptionGetDto= {};
  constructor( 
    //private cookieService:CookieService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private questionService:QuestionsService,
    private answerOption: AnswerOptionsService,
    //private testService: TestsService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router, 
    
    ){}
    form: FormGroup;
    @Input()
    tinymceInit;
    model:AnswerOptionGetDto;
  modelo: AnswerOptionGetPreviewDto;
   modelB:QuestionGetDto[]=[];
   modelC:AnswerOptionGetIdDto;
  questionId: number;
  languageCode:string;
  //answerOptionId: number;//a
   value:number;
   
   modelAnswerSearch:AnswerOptionGetDto[]=[];//1
   errores_api: string[] = [];
   order: number = 0;

    @Output()
    modelA:AnswerOptionGetDto[]=[];//1
   
  
    //OnSubmit: EventEmitter<QuestionGetIdDto> = new EventEmitter<QuestionGetIdDto>();
  OnSubmit: EventEmitter<AnswerOptionPostDto> = new EventEmitter<AnswerOptionPostDto>();
  pass: EventEmitter<AnswerOptionGetDto> = new EventEmitter<AnswerOptionGetDto>();
    OnCancel: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.questionId = params.questionId;
      this.languageCode = 'es',
      console.log('paso el ID:');
      console.log('paso el LC:');
    });
    this.getQuestionData(this.questionId);
    console.log("view 1");



    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      answerText: ['', { validators: [Validators.required] }],//a
      //value: (''),
      //order: (''),
      value: [0],
      order: [this.order]
    });
if (this.modelo !== undefined) {
      this.form.patchValue(this.modelo);
    }
    this.form.valueChanges
      .subscribe(valor => {

        this.buscarPorId(valor);
      });

    //this.getQuestionData(this.questionId);

    /*this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.testid = params.id;
      this.url = this.router.routerState.snapshot.url;
      //console.log('url ' + this.url);
    });
    }
  }*/
      this.getQuestionData(this.questionId);
      }

     buscarPorId(valor:any){
       var arr=[]
       var x: number
       this.modelAnswerSearch=[];
       this.modelA.forEach(x => {
       x===this.questionId? this.modelC=x:null}) ,
       console.log("modelC");
      console.log(x);
      console.log("modelAnswerSearch");
      console.log(this.modelAnswerSearch);
     
    }
  //});
  
     //}

       getQuestionData(questionId:number){
        this.answerOption.obtenerOpcionesPregunta$Json({
          questionId:1,
          //answerOptionId:1,
          languageCode: 'es',
          includeHATEOAS: 'n',
          platformId: 1,
          'x-languageCode': 'es',
      
        }).subscribe(respuesta=>{
          this.modelA=respuesta.answerOptions,
           this.modelAnswerSearch=respuesta.answerOptions;
           
           //this.modelB=respuesta.questions;
           console.log(this.modelAnswerSearch);
           //console.log(this.modelB)
        },  errores => {
          this.errores_api = parsearErroresAPI(errores);
          
        });
        

      
       }
  
  
      guardarCambios(){
       this.OnSubmit.emit(this.form.value);
       console.log("guardado");
    
      }
  
     
    }
```

y su html es este:

```html
<div class="container" *ngIf="modelAnswerSearch" >

    <div class="row"  >
   <form class="form"  [formGroup]="form"> 
         <div class="form-row" *ngFor="let item of modelAnswerSearch; let index=index">
           <div class="form-group col-md-12 ">
             <h3>Editar por reactivo</h3>
             <div class="bloqueTexto ">
               Escribe el texto de la respuesta.Puedes insertar elementos multimedia como imágenes y video. <br />
               Puedes agregar otra opción de respuesta después de guardar esta. <br />
               No es necesario escribir el inciso o identificador de la respuesta.

             </div>

             <!--lo más cercano al template-->
             <label>Descripción</label>

             <editor [init]="{}" initialValue="{{item.answerText}}"></editor>

             <div class="form-group col-md-2 controles">
               <label for="value"><strong>Puntaje</strong></label>
               <div>

                 <input type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        id="value"
                        formControlName="value"
                        aria-describedby="puntaje"
                        placeholder={{item.value}}
                        required>

               </div>
               <div>
                 <label for="order"><strong>Orden</strong></label>
                 <input type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        id="order"
                        formControlName="order"
                        aria-describedby="orden"
                        placeholder={{item.order}}
                        required>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-9 col-xs-12 text-right">
               <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
                 <div>
                   <button mat-flat-button color="warn" (click)="guardarCambios()">
                     Guardar Cambios
                   </button>
                 </div>
                 
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </form>
   </div>             
</div>
```

¿Alguna idea?, en serio he tratado de resolverlo y pues necesito ayuda, gracias

Comment: modelA:AnswerOptionGetDto[]=[]..> no veo la interfaz que lo define pero si es un array de objetos cuando recibis el parametro en buscarPorId(valor:any que muestra console.log("modelC");---> de acuerdo a lo anterior map,filter?